# Bugzilla gives Internal Server Error after Ubuntu and Perl upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, perl, bugzilla

I've just upgraded a server running a Bugzilla installation from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 (this also comes with a Perl 5.18 to 5.22 upgrade).  Bugzilla is configured as a virtual host in Apache.  After the upgrade, accessing Bugzilla returns an "Internal Server Error"

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at Bugzilla-URL Port 80

The Apache error log `/var/log/apache2/error.log` has only one line related to this error:

```
[Tue Apr 30 08:34:21.227311 2019] [cgid:error] [pid 90210:tid 86753098675309] [client url:port] End of script output before headers: index.cgi
```

I haven't been able to find out a whole lot about this error.  It seems to refer to the file `/var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi`, which does exist on the system:

```
$ sudo ls -Alh /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi
-rwxr-x--- 1 root www-data 2.2K May 12  2016 /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi
```

One person in [this post](http://debian.2.n7.nabble.com/Bug-847961-gitweb-missing-dependency-to-libcgi-pm-perl-td4013108.html) had that error line thrown by Gitweb after the same upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.  In this case, the Perl upgrade 5.18 -> 5.22 removed the perl module `CGI.pm`, which is provided by the package `libcgi-pm-perl`; installing `libcgi-pm-perl` fixed it.  I did not get any error message about a missing module, however, and `libcgi-pm-perl` is already installed on my system (v4.26-1 from Ubuntu main).

Another answer on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310952/upgraded-ubuntu-from-14-04-lts-to-16-04-lts-and-bugzilla-stopped-working#39310953) points out Bugzilla's `checksetup.pl` utility, which sounds useful.  When I attempt to run it, however, I get a segfault:

```
# perl /var/www/bugzilla/checksetup.pl
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, how do I diagnose the problem at this point?

Please note that I'm more interested in determining what's wrong than I am in making Bugzilla work.  I welcome and appreciate any thoughts on troubleshooting, but if you want to suggest a solution, I'm not going to try it unless you can also tell me what you think is wrong and why what you suggest will help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me on openSUSE Leap 15.1 can be found at [Bugzilla checksetup.pl stops with segmentation fault](https://blog.spaps.de/bugzilla-checksetup-pl-stops-with-segmentation-fault/):

1. Rename the lib folder in the Bugzilla directory
2. Run ./install-modules –all
3. Run ./checksetup.pl again

Note that in step 2, I had to run `./install-module.pl -all`